# Around 1k database connections in TIME_WAIT state. Should I worry?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I do a netstat `netstat -an | grep :3306 | grep TIME_WAIT| sort |wc -l`, I see around thousand connections. Should I worry about this? What is the acceptable number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you should worry at this point, you should keep a look on errors in the log related to "unable to connect", "unable to authenticate", "mysql disappeared" - these show that the load (connection wise) on the server isn't allowing new connection or existing connections to finish their queries.